# How can I check if one expression implies another?

Tags: functions, symbolic

Say I have one expression, for example $x^3-3 + c = y$, and I want to check if it implies another with some set of explicitly stated assumptions.  With the previous example, assuming all variables are positive real numbers, we might ask if $x^3-3 + c = y$ implies $c = -x^3 + y$.  This example is trivial,  but I'd like to do the same where, perhaps, choices can be made about the use of various special functions or identities and there can also be inequalities.

Is there something like `ImpliesQ[{exp1,exp2}]`?

Comment: `Implies[x^3 - 3 + c == y, c == y - x^3] // Reduce`

Comment: @rasher Wham. :)

Comment: @Nasser The example I choose was a poor one... I was thinking more along the lines of there being some choice for special functions / etc. in one derivation vs. another, and then making sure that the results are the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Simplify[c == y - x^3, Assumptions -> x^3 - 3 + c == y]
```

> False

```
Simplify[c == y - x^3 + 3, Assumptions -> x^3 - 3 + c == y]
```

> True

Answer (score 1):

It's simply `` Assumptions`ImpliesQ ``.